# How can I get the the half of elements of a list?

Tags: c#, linq, list

The problem is: I got a list of elements and then I use group by. I need to get another list where contains the half of elements from each group by.

How can I do that? I'm using LINQ.

UPDATE:

This is the first list that I get.

```
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);
        var conditions = from c in xdoc.Descendants("Condition")
                         select new
                         {
                             ObjectiveID = (int)c.Attribute("ObjectiveID"),
                             TypeID = (int)c.Attribute("TypeID"),
                             ProblemID = (int)c.Attribute("ProblemID"),
                             Ranges = (from r in c.Descendants("Range")
                                       select new
                                       {
                                           Decimals = (int)r.Attribute("Decimals"),
                                           Min = (decimal)r.Attribute("Min"),
                                           Max = (decimal)r.Attribute("Max")
                                       }).ToArray(),
                         };
```

That's the original which I'm using. From that one, I only want to get the half of problems from each OBJECTIVEID.

If in the enummerable I have 2 elements of the same objectiveID, I must get only one. If I got one problem, I must get only one, If I have 5 I'd have 2 or 3.

Comment: please show some source code...

Comment: How do you define half?  First half / last half? or alternate elements?

Comment: As you like it.. for me, it'll be good first or alternate. I think that wouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking -- are you trying to get individual elements from each group into another list? If so, SelectMany is probably what you're looking for.

```
var numbers = new[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
var evensAndOdds = numbers.GroupBy(x => x % 2);
var evens = evensAndOdds.Where(g => g.Key == 0).SelectMany(g => g).ToList();
var odds =  evensAndOdds.Where(g => g.Key == 1).SelectMany(g => g).ToList();
```

Alternatively:

```
var evens = evensAndOdds.Single(g => g.Key == 0).ToList();
```

---

*Response to Edit*

There's an overload of Select that also includes an integer index -- you can use this to filter out all the odd or even items to get half of the set.

You could change it to something like

```
Ranges = c.Descendants("Range")
          .Select((range,i) => new { range, i })
          .Where(pair => pair.i % 2 == 0) // select only even items
          .Select(pair => new {
               Decimals = (int)pair.range.Attribute("Decimals"),
               ... etc...
          })
          .ToArray()
```

---

I'm beginning to think I don't understand the question. If the problem is that you have data like

```
condition1: objectiveID = 2 problemID = 100
condition2: objectiveID = 2 problemID = 101
```

and you don't want two different problemIDs for the same objectiveID, you can use GroupBy / SelectMany / Take to narrow down to only one problem per objectiveID

```
xdoc.Descendants("Condition")
    .GroupBy(c => c.Attribute("objectiveID").value)
    .SelectMany(group => group.Take(1))
```

Comment: Well, I supposed that use group would be a good idea.. please, check the update.. because the problem is, later.. I need to undo that group by

Comment: I don't see any group bys in your updated code, what does "the half of elements from each group by." mean?

Comment: Well, the below code which I posted I supposed later I need to use a group by to do that..

I really want to get the half of problems from each OBJECTIVEID

Comment: I get your idea. I'm not sure how can I add this code.. so, I don't have the neccesity to use a group by?

Comment: You do need to use the groupby, you just need to use a `selectmany(group => group.Take(1))` to accomplish your objective of "only taking one problem for each objectiveID"

Comment: Mmm only one more thing I want to add hehe. If I have 5 I'd have 2 or 3. Do I make myself clear? I wanted to expose the arbitrary cases.

Comment: 3 -- group[0], group[2], and group[4] would be included.

Comment: Please Jimmy, put the another answer.. xDocDescendants("Condition".GroupBy...SelectMany..) I only changed the value to group.Count()/2 .. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

For an arbitrary `IEnumerable` you can get an alternating split into two lists using:-

```
var oneHalf = list.Select((x, i) => new {x, i}).Where(t => t.i%2 == 0).Select(t =>t.x);
var otherHalf = list.Select((x, i) => new {x, i}).Where(t => t.i%2 != 0).Select(t =>t.x);
```